# Merging 2 Woocommerce Databases

Tags: database, csv, woocommerce, merge, export

I've got two Wordpress+Woocommerce stores, one is for wholesale, the other is a regular store with an existing database. My client wants to merge the two.

I've:

- Exported wholesale products, and imported them into the regular store
- Exported wholesale users as a CSV, and imported them into the regular store
- Repeated the process for orders

The issue I'm having is, I can't import users as is, as some users in the target store have the same ID (although they're different customers, different names, different email addresses). They get skipped when importing, otherwise, I'd be updating or overriding existing users.

I've tried editing the CSV before import by giving users new IDs I know aren't in use. The import went fine until I noticed orders aren't linked properly. All orders are under 'Guest' instead of being linked to their user. Products aren't linked to their order either, although their ID and SKU have been kept the same.

How can I make this work?

Comment: First you should have to keep the track of old user ids with the new ones… Then first import users. Then edit orders CSV to replace in `_customer_user` column the old user ID with the new user ID… So something long and boring.

Comment: "First you should have to keep the track of old user ids with the new ones" What do you mean by this? And you're right, I hadn't thought of updating the _customer_user column. Although I don't see how to do this without doing it one by one as I have multiple orders for some customers. I can't really auto-fill with chronological numbers like I did in the customers CSV?

Comment: You could also make a SQL query, to update the user ID (in `wp_users`, `wp_users` and `wp_postmeta` for `_customer_user` meta `meta_key`) adding for example a fixed number to all users IDs on the old database. This number to be added should be higher than the higher user ID from the database where you want to import that users and orders

Comment: This kind of SQL query is a much more easy process that can be done in few minutes… Then you will be able to export all users and orders and import them directly, without loosing time.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Would that ensure orders are linked to these users as well? How would that part work?

Comment: Yes as this SQL query changes the user ID everywhere it's needed (by adding to it a number calculated from the other database highest user ID). Ask a developer in your location that has some skills with MySQL.